# Difference between Sling Content Project and Sling Bundle Project

Tags: eclipse, sling

I want to create a Sling project in Eclipse (`File > New > Other > Sling`). There are two types of projects I can choose from:

1. Sling Content Project
2. Sling Bundle Project

What is the difference between a Sling Content Project and a Sling Bundle Project?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific what you mean with `Sling content project` and `Sling bundle project`?

Comment: In eclipse I tried to create apache sling project. where I found 2 type of project creation option 1) Sling bundle project 2) sling content project under the menu file->new->other->Sling

Answer (score 4):

**Sling Bundle Project**: This project contains your Java code. This is were you can add your OSGi services, models etc.

**Sling Content Project**: Content projects contain the content you want to deploy to your JCR repository (which is part of Sling). Content in this case mostly means XML files which describe the content structure that is added to the repository. But it can also contain JavaScript and CSS files or images.

Note that these are two templates provided by the [Sling IDE Tooling for Eclipse](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/ide-tooling.html) and intended as starting points.